# Search bar going to next line

Tags: html, css

So I have a search box but everytime I resize the window and shrink it , it sends it to a new line.

I tried adding float to it but it completely made it look weird. It would push it to the right and shrink it and still go to a new line.

This is my CSS

```
.search-container {
    margin-left: 35%;
    margin-top: 8px;
}
.search-container input[type=text] {
  padding: 6px;
  border: solid;
  border-color: #c4baba;
 border-width: 1px;
  margin-right: -4px;
  font-size: 17px;
  width: 38%;
 background: #121212;
}
.topnav .search-container button {
  padding: 7px 10px;

  /*margin-right: 35%;*/
  background: #ddd;
  font-size: 17px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

This is the HTML

```
<div class="topnav">
        <a class="active" href="#home">----Image----</a> 
        <a href="#news">Discover</a>
        <a href="#contact">Following</a>
        <div class="search-container">
            <form action="/action_page.php">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." name="search">
            <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
            </form>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use flexbox to achieve this behavior. See what I added to `.topnav`.

```css
.topnav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
}

.search-container {
  margin-left: 35%;
  margin-top: 8px;
}

.search-container input[type=text] {
  padding: 6px;
  border: solid;
  border-color: #c4baba;
  border-width: 1px;
  margin-right: -4px;
  font-size: 17px;
  width: 38%;
  background: #121212;
}

.topnav .search-container button {
  padding: 7px 10px;
  /*margin-right: 35%;*/
  background: #ddd;
  font-size: 17px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav">
  <a class="active" href="#home">----Image----</a>
  <a href="#news">Discover</a>
  <a href="#contact">Following</a>
  <div class="search-container">
    <form action="/action_page.php">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." name="search">
      <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
    </form>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: this doesnt seem to work. just ruins it more for me

Comment: @htmlhelp32 please read on how to use flexbox or do layout with other tools like css grid or bootstrap. my fix is a quick fix which doesn't wrap the search bar in a new line and that's what you're asking for.

Answer (score 0):

I used float:right and then and set its position with right and top.

```css
 .search-container {
 float:right;
 right:3px;
 top:8px;
 }
 .search-container input[type=text] {
 padding: 6px;
 border: solid;
 border-color: #c4baba;
 border-width: 1px;
 margin-right: -4px;
 font-size: 17px;
 width: 38%;
 background: #121212;
 }
.topnav .search-container button {
 padding: 7px 10px;

 /*margin-right: 35%;*/
 background: #ddd;
 font-size: 17px;
 border: none;
 cursor: pointer;
 }
```

```html
 <div class="topnav">
    <a class="active" href="#home">----Image----</a> 
    <a href="#news">Discover</a>
    <a href="#contact">Following</a>
    <div class="search-container">
        <form action="/action_page.php">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." name="search">
        <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
        </form>
    </div>

  </div>
```